# What is the difference between these sum notations? $\sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j \overset{?}{=} \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j$

Tags: summation, notation, index-notation

I saw both written in a textbook (cannot remember where exactly), but I do not know what the difference should be between these:

$$\sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j \overset{?}{=} \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j$$

Comment: What are the ranges of $i$ and $j$? If both are finite, the two sums are the same. But if they are infinite, then one sum might exist while the other does not.

Comment: @5xum I think that they were not specified, but I think finite. It's a notation we had in some physics based problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explicitly has order defined on the sum
$\sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j = \sum_i (\sum_j a_i b_j) =\sum_j a_1 b_j +  \sum_j a_2 b_j +\sum_j a_3 b_j +\cdots $

or even if one insists that there is no order for indexes then

$\sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j = a_{19265} \sum_j b_j +  a_{1} \sum_j b_j +  a_{991} \sum_j b_j  +\cdots $

where as $\sum_{i,j} a_i b_j$ does not explicitly define any particular order e.g.
$\sum_{i,j} a_i b_j = a_{189}b_0 + a_1b_{7676} + a_1b_1$ etc.

For convergence with some multidimensional series the order matters, where as with changing the order could converge to any value.